# Use not custom fields in get_posts() meta_query?

Tags: wp-query, get-posts, meta-query

Is it possible to use not custom fields in `get_posts()`'s `'meta_query'` to use a `or`-relation statement with a custom field and a category id?

Like this:

```
$args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 6
      , 'offset'         => 0
      , 'meta_query'     => array(
                                 'relation' => 'OR'
                               , array(
                                      'key'   => 'placing'
                                    , 'value' => 'nn'
                                 )
                               , array(
                                      'key'   => 'category_id'
                                    , 'value' => $cat->term_id
                                 )
                            )
    );

$myposts = get_posts($args);
```

And if so, should it be `term_id` or `category_id`?

Or how do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't work like that because `meta_query` is for custom fields and `tax_query` is for taxonomies.

But what you could do is run two separate queries to get all of the IDs that qualify, and then use those IDs in a 3rd query with `post__in`. For example:

```
$cat_query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'cat'            => '63',
);

$meta_query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'placing',
            'value' => 'nn',
        )
    )
);

$cat_query  = get_posts( $cat_query_args  );
$meta_query = get_posts( $meta_query_args );

$merged_posts = array_merge( $cat_query, $meta_query );

$combined_query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'offset'         => 0,
    'post__in'       => $merged_posts
);

$combined_posts = get_posts( $combined_query_args );
```